# PayPal POODLE Fix broke our legacy Java site checkout

Tags: java, ssl, paypal, legacy, payflowpro

We have a legacy Java site (JRE 1.4.2/Tomcat 4.1/Apache -- all very legacy versions) that processes payments through a likewise legacy version of PayFlow Pro, and were concerned when PayPal recently notified us that support for SSL 3.0 would be ending.

The reason is that we cannot actively develop anything related to checkout on our site due to the lack of a functional development environment (checkout functionality has been broken on our development environment since before my time with the company).

I reached out to our hosting provider with this issue, and they immediately disabled SSL 3.0 on our Apache server. I tested the site via Qualys' service (http://ssllabs.com), and it confirmed that SSL 3.0 is not supported, and several test checkouts I performed worked perfectly.

However, I tried another test checkout this morning, and an unspecified error (see partial stack trace from catalina.out below) caused the VM to crash:

```
An unexpected exception has been detected in native code outside the VM.
Unexpected Signal : 11 occurred at PC=0x9C1C1AB4
Function=__umoddi3+0x0
Library=/home/tomcat/bin/libpfpro.so
```

I'm guessing that there's some sort of issue with the libpfpro.so library, but I have absolutely no idea how to approach fixing it, since we don't have an in-house Java developer, and the previous developer has stated in the past that the site's configuration is a bit of a mystery.

I'm looking, either, for some direction as to how to fix the "unexpected exception" due to the PayFlow Pro library or some resources to help us locate on-demand Java expert(s) that may be able to help us resolve this.

Comment: We recently encountered a similar issue. Research showed that we could only get around the problem by rebuilding the legacy app under Java 7 and hosting it under Tomcat-7. All other attempts failed because support for SSL3 is just not available in the JVM under early JREs. You may find it available in JRE-6 but it certainly is not available in JRE-5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it a matter of SSL3 not being supported, since PayPal has discontinued support for SSL3? I'm thinking it's the legacy version of the PayFlow Pro library that expects API responses to use SSL3? What's stumping me is that our host deactivated SSL 3 on our Apache server, and we didn't have any issues until PayPal actually pulled the plug.

Comment: Apologies - my mistake. The problem is that to avoid POODLE attacks you must disable SSL3 as it is the vulnerable component. Unfortunately this means that all https access **must** use a newer protocol such as TLS and TLS may not be available in JRE-1.4. Deactivating SSL3 probably just forced your tool to use something older. Now it cannot do that.